# How does a browser compile source code?

Tags: google-chrome, web, compilation

everyone, a newbie here!

Today I have a question about how Chrome browser knows what to do after reading the source file. More generally, I am trying to understand what happens when we run our .js files in Chrome.

Here is what I mean specifically. Imagine you are a source code that lives inside Chrome. Beyond a random LCD monitor screen, a person aka user makes an interaction with the website that you are rendering, that asks you to call `drive()` function which is dependent on so many other functions.

There are two ways (or more...) that we humans drive. First, you drive just by muscle memory. On the other hand, when you are first learning to drive, you should learn how accelerator, brakes, and headlight works. After some time, you can drive effortlessly.

So here it comes the question. Does chrome know what to do by muscle memory, or does it learn from the very top to bottom what to do. If this is the case, does it have to learn all again when it encounters `drive()` function the second time?

*I know this could be a compiler-related 'duplicate' question, but I am a newbie and don't know enough keywords to look up what I need... Also thought asking about how web browsers work.

Comment: Chrome, or another browser parses the HTML. Any JS that is found is executed from top down (besides function hoisting that happens). Any event-related code that is ran (or initiated by the JS from the source code) stays in memory. When an event or trigger for any of these events is hit, Chrome simply goes back to the address of the function of code you defined and runs it again.

Comment: Wow, if it runs again, now I do believe that computer is really fast.. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score -3):

Web browsers do not "compile" the code in the traditional sense like a compiler does with languages like C++ or Java. Instead, web browsers interpret and execute the code using various engines and components. Let's take a look at the process of how web browsers handle code:

1. **HTML Parsing**: When you load a webpage, the browser first retrieves the HTML content of the page. It then parses the HTML document, building a Document Object Model (DOM) tree, which represents the structure of the page.
2. **CSS Parsing and Rendering**: After parsing the HTML, the browser fetches and parses any associated CSS files. It then constructs a CSS Object Model (CSSOM) that describes the style rules of the page. The DOM and CSSOM are combined to create the Render Tree, which represents how elements will be displayed on the page.
3. **JavaScript Execution**: If the HTML or JavaScript code references external resources like images or scripts, the browser fetches those resources while continuing to parse the rest of the HTML. When it encounters a `<script>` tag or inline JavaScript, the browser pauses HTML parsing, fetches the script (if external), and then executes the JavaScript code.
4. **JavaScript Engine**: Each browser has its own JavaScript engine (e.g., V8 in Chrome, SpiderMonkey in Firefox, JavaScriptCore in Safari) responsible for executing JavaScript code. The engine converts JavaScript code into machine code using Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation or other optimization techniques to improve performance.
5. **Event Handling**: As the page loads and while users interact with it, events (e.g., clicks, scrolls) are generated. JavaScript code can listen for these events and respond accordingly, updating the DOM and CSSOM as needed.
6. **Reflow and Repaint**: As the DOM or CSSOM is updated, the browser performs a reflow and repaint process to reflect these changes on the screen. Reflow recalculates the positions and sizes of elements, while repaint updates the pixels on the screen.
7. **Rendering**: After all necessary resources are loaded and JavaScript has executed, the browser combines the final DOM, CSSOM, and Render Tree to render the complete webpage on the screen.

It's important to note that web browsers do not have a single compilation step like traditional compilers. Instead, they perform various steps, including parsing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, executing JavaScript code in the JavaScript engine, and rendering the final result on the screen. This process is repeated whenever a page is loaded or updated, allowing for dynamic and interactive web experiences.

Comment: Looks like generated with AI tools